# Firebase 3.x issue: FIRUserInfo is an "undeclared identifier"

Tags: ios, firebase

No matter what I try, FIRUserInfo is an undeclared identifier. I'm trying to migrate from Firebase 2.x to 3.x: somehow the recent changes on google/firebase server side broke my app's facebook auth integration.

I made sure my Podfile installs FirebaseAuth 3.0.2. I made sure my header does import @FirebaseAuth. I tried cleaning my build folder, restarting xcode etc.

In Xcode 7.3.1 I can command-click FIRUserInfo and it does indeed find the header file in the pod framework as expected. But it won't compile - the last line below fails with FIRUserInfo as undeclared identifier.

```
@import Firebase;
...
                [[FIRAuth auth] signInWithCredential:credential completion:^(FIRUser * _Nullable user, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                    if (error || user.providerData.count < 1) {
                        DDLogWarn(@"Firebase login after facebook failed: %@", error);
                        if( weakSelf.signInCompletionHandler ) {
                            weakSelf.signInCompletionHandler(false, false, nil);
                            weakSelf.signInCompletionHandler = nil;
                        }
                    } else {
                        FIRDatabaseReference *userRef = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
                        userRef = [userRef child:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"users/%@", user.uid]];
                        FIRUserInfo *profile = user.providerData.firstObject;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer. Change this: `FIRUserInfo *profile`
... to this:

```
id<FIRUserInfo> profile
```

Man I must have been REALLY tired to miss that. 
Sorry for yelling, internets...

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
```

In your Podfile an

```
@import Firebase;
```

Rather than the specific module - this should import the correct modules automatically.

Comment: Try cleaning the build folder - open the menu, hold down option and select Clean in Xcode, see if that makes progress?

Comment: I have done all of those things, doesn't work. I also checked with import Firebase as well as with import FirebaseAuth. Neither work.

Comment: Also, if I copy-paste FIRUserInfo's protocol definition to the end of my header file, it says duplicate protocol definition. WTF! It's a duplicate if I make it myself but it's an undeclared identifier?! grrr

Comment: ... and if I don't manually import FirebaseDatabase and I only import Firebase, then I cannot use FIRDatabaseReference. That means that import Firebase does not import the correct modules automatically (for me)

Comment: Thanks Thats Helps my problem on SWIFT Voted UP

Answer (score 0):

i am new in ios and have same problem
use

```
#import <FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth.h>
```

instead of

```
@import Firebase;
```

may it help..

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem of undeclared type with FIRDatabaseReference, and cannot fix it by updating the pod-file.

Finally, I find out a solution.

Google teach us to import only

> import Firebase

Just add:

> import FirebaseDatabase

and everything will become fine